# How to get hostname like from ping -a command?

Tags: android

When I use `ping -a 192.168.1.15`, I get:

`Pinging EDGE [192.168.1.15] with 32 bytes of data: ...`

But when using `InetAddress.getHostName()`, I am getting:

`Hostname is: 192.168.1.15`

Why is that, how do I get `EDGE` instead of ip address?

PS. `GetCanonicalHostname()` returns ip address as well.

This is probably because it is not DNS name, but NETBIOS name... is it possible to get that from ip address? How?

Comment: is this your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following **code** and see if it works.

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.15");
System.out.println(host.getHostName());
```

Comment: As I said in question this returns IP address.